# How to set anchor for wicket listview panel update with ajax

Tags: java, html, ajax, wicket

I have a ListView within a panel that has vertical scrolling enabled and absolute positioning using css.  When I select an IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink that was added to the listView it updates other panels on the page to provide futher information/options for the listItem.  It also refreshes the listView to add a css class to highlight the selected listItem.  I am trying to add an anchor to the listView so that it will render scrolled to display the selected listItem.

Problem: When I select an item down the list the listView will reload scrolled to the top of the panel, instead of to selected item.  Is this possible without a url redirect & full page reload?

markup:

```
<div wicket:id="psbContainer" style="position: absolute; top: 325px; height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; left: 4px; right: 305px;">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr wicket:id="psbList" valign="top">
            <td><a wicket:id="viewRelated"><span wicket:id="psbNum"/></a></td>
            <td wicket:id="summary"/>
            <td wicket:id="psbMilestone"/>
            <td wicket:id="dueDate"/>
            <td wicket:id="devCount"/>
            <td wicket:id="activeCount"/>
            <td wicket:id="ccCount"/>
            <td wicket:id="team"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

java:

```
    psbListView = new ListView("psbList", psbList) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem listItem) {
            final Space psb = (Space) listItem.getModelObject();
            if(psb.equals(psbSelected)) {
                listItem.add(selected);
            }
            // viewRelated ========================================================
            IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink viewRelated = new IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink("viewRelated") {
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    psbSelected = psb;
                    target.addComponent(pslpContainer);
                }
            };
            this.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            this.setMarkupId(psb.getPsbNum());
            viewRelated.setAnchor(this);
            viewRelated.add(new Label("psbNum", new Model(psb.getPsbNum())));
            listItem.add(viewRelated);
            ...
```

Comment: Something like `target.addJavascript( "getElementById( \""+this.getMarkupId()+"\").scrollIntoView()");` in `onClick()` should do the trick. (It's probably not syntactically correct but I can't check it and you hopefully get the idea anyway.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just refresh the current selected item (along with the previously selected item) instead of the whole list?

Comment: @Nicktar - I have not been successful in performing ajax updates for items within a listView, wicket updates the last item in the listView, so I have been updating the entire list.  If you are familiar with how to do that I would appreciate the insight.  I am using wicket 1.4.17, but planning to update soon to 6.

Comment: @OnesAndZeros have you tried the suggestions from [this article](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/) on the wicket in action blog?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have not yet been successfull in implementing them, and got pulled to something more urgent.  I will update when sucessful.

Comment: @biziclop I was not able to get your suggestion to work.  It may have to do with my lousy javascript skills...  I like Wicket because I don't have to think about how bad I am at javascript ;{> Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @Nicktar  I have looked into the suggestions from the article you recommend, but I am not good enough with javascript to figure out how to modify to update a row as opposed to adding a new row.  Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just update the client side css styling using pure javascript in the AjaxRequestTarget? Probably not more than

```
ListItem<?> previousSelected = ...;
ListItem<?> currentSelected = ...;

target.appendJavaScript("document.getElementById('" + previousSelected.getMarkupId() + "').className=\"\";");
target.appendJavaScript("document.getElementById('" + currentSelected.getMarkupId() + "').className=\"selected\";");
```

This way you don't have to update the whole listview to just change some classes.

Comment: Thanks Martijin.  I did finally get back to working on this issue and my code is as you described, I just had to make sure that I setMarkupId() & setOutputMarkupId().  I also added new Behavior() with response.render(OnLoadHeaderItem.forScript(... so that the indicator would show on the page load & refresh correctly.  Thanks again.